# How to make Siddhi basic authentication work

Tags: http, authentication, siddhi

I'm attempting to setup a simple Siddhi flow where I receive a message using an http listener, use a field from that message as an input to an http API call, then log the result.
The problem I'm having is I cannot seem to get basic http authentication to work on the API call.  It seems to just not send an Authorization header.  Here is the Siddhi flow I built:

```
@App:name('Test Flow')
@App:description('Listen, call, log')

@source(type = 'http', receiver.url = "http://0.0.0.0:8007/myListener", 
    @map(type = 'json', 
        @attributes(someInputField = "$.someInputField")))
@sink(type = 'http-call', publisher.url = "https://somehost.com/someApiPath", sink.id = "callAPI.sink", basic.auth.username = "testUser", basic.auth.password = "testPass", https.truststore.file = "/usr/local/ssl/keystore.jks", https.truststore.password = "someTruststorePass", headers = "'Content-Type: application/json'", method = "POST", hostname.verification.enabled = "true", 
    @map(type = 'json', 
        @payload(""" { "someStandardPayloadField: "abc", "someInputField": "{{someInputField}}" } """)))
define stream APIStream (someInputField string);

@source(type = 'http-call-response', sink.id = "callAPI.sink", http.status.code = "200", 
    @map(type = 'json', enclosing.element = "$.outputs", 
        @attributes(someResponseField = "someOutputfield")))
@sink(type = 'log', prefix = "LOGGER")
define stream logStream (someResponseField string);
```

Comment: Authorization header is sent here https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-http/blob/master/component/src/main/java/io/siddhi/extension/io/http/sink/HttpSink.java#L1023 Did you check the headers?

Comment: What is the response you get from the http-call sink, in this case?